# Newtonsoft.Json : Compilation Error during deployment to IIS SERVER.

Tags: c#, json, iis, json.net

I developed a website using Visual Web developer 2013. I have installed Newtonsoft.JSON via the package manager console. The website runs fine when I click debug in Visual Studio. Newtonsoft.Json.dll exists under the Bin folder.

I get the following error when I navigate to the website

The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I want to know if I need to prepare the server for deployment.

Comment: What version of .NET are you running on your server? If it is older than the version of Newtonsoft you are using that would cause you problems.

Comment: commented the line "using Newtonsoft.Json;" and it started working as desired.. thats weird

Comment: My guess is that it could be an unused using; you had the dll in your bin and built without cleaning.

Comment: I am using .NET 4.0.30319

Comment: Hi garryp, there was no option to clean the build, I am using the Visual Web developer express edition. I started with "New website" and I only get the "build" option, not the "clean" option in the menu under "debug".  Am I doing it the wrong way, I was running out of time and will spend some time over the weekend if you point me towards best practices to build a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Web Developer:

1) In Solution Explorer, select the project.
2) On the Project menu, click  Properties.
3) Click Reference Paths.

Then check the path of the the refence to Newtonton.Json and make sure that is it a relative reference to an assembly that you also have during your deployment. Two possible errors are that you either reference an assmebly stored in some other folder, or that you are taking the reference from some other project.